# Is interaction a relevant perturbation for 1d Anderson localization of fermions?

Tags: condensed-matter, renormalization, anderson-localization

Disorder is a relevant perturbation in 1d, which drives the system to Anderson localization. My question is if I am already at the Anderson localization fixed point, how to analyze the scaling dimensions of the fermions, and how to determine if the local fermion interaction is relevant or not?

Comment: When Anderson localization happens, fermion correlation functions are not scale invariant, so what does relevant/irrelevant mean? In a sense it is infinitely irrelevant.